# Lock-free variant of wait/notify

Tags: java, multithreading

Java requires a thread to own the monitor of `o` before calling `o.wait()` or `o.notify()`. This is a well-known fact. However, are mutex locks fundamentally required for any such mechanism to work? What if there was an API which provided

```
compareAndWait
```

and

```
setAndNotify
```

instead, combining a CAS action with thread scheduling/descheduling? This would have some advantages:

- threads about to enter the waiting state would not impede the progress of notifying threads;
- they would also not have to wait on each other before being allowed to check the waiting condition;
- on the notifying side any number of producer threads could proceed simultaneously.

Is there a fundamental, insurmountable obstacle to providing such an API?

Comment: The `Lock` is written without using wait/notify. It uses CAS under the bonnet.

Comment: But we still have to acquire the Lock to work with its Condition.

Comment: Could you expand a little on what `compareAndWait` and `setAndNotify` would do? `compareAndWait` sounds like a `Semaphore` to me while `setAndNotify` sounds like a `BlockingQueue.put()`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon The analogy with a Semaphore is a good one. So a conclusion could be that such a feature does exist and `wait`/`notify` is specifically useful for cases where you actually need locking.

Comment: What does "lock free variant of wait/notify" mean?  A lock-free _algorithm_ is one that guarantees that at any time, there will always be at least one participating thread that is able to make progress.  But, what does "make progress" mean when the purpose of the algorithm is to make threads _wait_ for something?

Comment: @jameslarge I tried to explain exactly what advantages this would give. I used "lock-free" as in "doesn't use mutex locks", not in the sense of the definition you used. Plus, the algorithm to make the notification _is_ lock-free in the book sense as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More of a thought experiment than some real working code but this seems to work.

```
// My lock class.
public static class Padlock<E extends Enum<E>> {

    // Using Markable because I think I'm going to need it.
    public final AtomicReference<E> value;
    // Perhaps use a set to maintain all waiters.
    Set<Thread> waiters = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    public Padlock(E initialValue) {
        this.value = new AtomicReference<>(initialValue);
    }

    /**
     * Waits for the locks value to become the specified key value.
     *
     * @param waitFor - The desired key.
     */
    public void compareAndWait(E waitFor) {
        log("Wait for " + waitFor);
        // Spin on the value.
        while (value.get() != waitFor) {
            log("Park waiting for " + waitFor);
            // Remember me as waiting.
            waiters.add(Thread.currentThread());
            // TODO: What do we do here??
            LockSupport.park();
            log("Awoke " + waitFor);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the locks value to the key value.
     *
     * If this resulted in a change - notify all changers.
     *
     * @param shouldBe - What it should be now.
     * @param makeIt - The new value to set.
     */
    public void setAndNotify(E shouldBe, E makeIt) {
        log("Set " + shouldBe + "->" + makeIt);
        if (value.compareAndSet(shouldBe, makeIt)) {
            log("Notify " + shouldBe + "->" + makeIt);
            // It changed! Notify the waiters.
            for (Thread t : waiters) {
                // Perhaps
                log("Unpark " + t.getName());
                LockSupport.unpark(t);
            }
        }
    }
}

enum State {

    Off, On;
}

private static final long TESTTIME = 30000;
private static final long TICK = 100;

private static final void log(String s) {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + s);

}

static class MutexTester implements Runnable {

    final Padlock<State> lock;

    public MutexTester(Padlock<State> lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        long wait = System.currentTimeMillis() + TESTTIME;
        do {
            // Wait for an On!
            lock.compareAndWait(Test.State.On);
            try {
                log("Got it!");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(TICK);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    log("Interrupted!");
                }
            } finally {
                // Release
                lock.setAndNotify(Test.State.On, Test.State.Off);
            }
        } while (System.currentTimeMillis() < wait);
        log("Done");
    }
}

static class RandomSwitcher implements Runnable {

    final Padlock<State> lock;
    final Random random = new Random();

    public RandomSwitcher(Padlock<State> lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        long wait = System.currentTimeMillis() + TESTTIME;
        do {
            // On!
            lock.setAndNotify(Test.State.Off, Test.State.On);
            log("On!");
            pause();
            lock.setAndNotify(Test.State.On, Test.State.Off);
            log("Off!");
            pause();
        } while (System.currentTimeMillis() < wait);
        log("Done");
    }

    private void pause() {
        try {
            // Random wait.
            Thread.sleep(TICK * random.nextInt(10));
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted! " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    final Padlock<State> lock = new Padlock<>(State.Off);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new MutexTester(lock));
    t1.start();
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new RandomSwitcher(lock));
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

I've implemented the protocol that `compareAndWait` waits for **exclusive** use while `setAndNotify` releases the mutex.

Comment: Nice work :) I think the primitive of choice for going to wait state, then being awoken, is `park`/`unpark`. These also take care of the "missed notify" issue because their semantics involve a sticky permit. But I think you were dead on with mentioning `Semaphore` in the comment. `setAndNotify` is exactly like `release`: semaphore's permits are not owned by threads.

Comment: And for the concurrent set you'd use `newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap()` or, better, `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Looks like [LockSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html) may have some useful mechanisms.

Comment: Yes, that's what I refer to by `park`,`unpark`.

Comment: Is it a glitch or the code that clears the waiters is omitted on purpose?

Comment: @Raffaele - It was a work-in-progress - it now may be working.

Comment: Cool, this looks good... but I think there's a race in `compareAndWait`: when you go back to re-check `value.get()`, it may fail either due to a spurious wakeup or because it got switched again by another thread. With wait/notify you usually want just one thread to "take" the permit, all others going back to sleep. Here several threads may go on (you can't control it). Semaphore's semantics would prevent that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - I knew there was a reason to use an `AtomicMarkableReference`!! No time now to fix it - sorry. Hope I've given you a good start.

Comment: Sure, and then some :)

Comment: The bigger problem of this approach is that it might miss updates completely. If a thread sets the desired value and notifies right before the waiting thread adds itself to the set, it won’t get notified. Of course, you won’t spot that problem in a test setup where it’s guaranteed that another matching update will happen sooner or later. But even if it worked, there is the semantic problem: right after `compareAndWait` returns, the value may have changed again, so why bother waiting for a particular value at all?

Comment: @Holger - I am making no statement concerning the feasability/functionality/thread-safety of this code. In fact there is a good chance it is full of holes. It is just an attempt to reflect Marko's desires in Java. As such, you are right - **there is a very good chance that this code will not work as desired**.

Answer (score 5):

There is no problem implementing arbitrary wait/notify mechanisms using [`LockSupport.park()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#park--) and [`LockSupport.unpark(Thread)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#unpark-java.lang.Thread-) as these basic primitives do not require holding any locks.

The reason why neither `Object.wait`/`Object.notify` nor [`Condition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)`.await`/`Condition.signal` offer you such a notification without holding a lock is a *semantic* one. The concept of the notification is that one thread waits for a condition to be fulfilled while another one stops the waiting when the condition has changed to the fulfilled state. Without holding a lock associated with that condition, there is no guaranty that the condition does not change in between tests for the condition’s state and the change of the thread’s state.

To be more specific, there is the possibility that when a thread which changed the condition notifies another thread, the condition has been modified again before the notification happens. But even worse, the condition could change to “fulfilled” before a thread starts to `wait` in which case the thread may miss a notification and hang forever.

Even if you are able to fuse the condition test and the wait operation into one atomic operation, it’s no help. Waiting for a condition is not an end in itself. The reason why a thread wants to wait for a condition is that it wants to perform an *action* for which the condition is a prerequisite and hence must not change while the action is performed. That’s the whole point: the condition test and the action must be implemented as one operation holding the lock, regardless of how the concept of a lock is implemented.

There are special cases where such problems cannot arise, e.g. when it is known that the condition’s state transitions are limited, thus you can preclude that the condition can go back to an unfulfilled state. That’s exactly what tools like `CountDownLatch`, `CyclicBarrier`, `Phaser` are for, but a notification mechanism with the predefined semantics of wait/notify implies not assuming such a special case.

Comment: This is mostly aligned with my thinking. But why does `wait/notify` _insist_ on the lock? Why isn't it left up to the implementor to decide whether they need it? I think it's connected to how the mechanism is implemented.

Comment: Also, it is not essential that the action after wakeup happens atomically with the wakeup: after weakeup we can attempt to acquire a work item, going back to sleep if nothing happens to be there. Actually the same thing must be implemented with the locked approach. But there may be difficulty in coordinating the wait set with the actual set of threads being put to sleep.

Comment: I don’t think that this is implementation dependent. Even with insisting on holding the lock, there are lots of things left which can be done wrong and it’s hard to image use cases where not holding the lock is not a bug. Especially all these cases where programmers ask “why do I have to own the lock” or are simply surprised by the `IllegalMonitorStateException` are examples of programmers not being aware that holding a lock is *semantically* required by what they are doing as otherwise they wouldn’t stumble about not holding the lock. I doubt that there is any counter-example.

Comment: Yes, there would be a race between checking the condition and calling `wait`. I think this is essential, but not the code after wakeup. That's why I proposed `compareAndWait`, to solve that particular race. But `compareAndWait` would have the issue of mantaining its internal wait set, so it may come down to a fundamental obstruction on the implementation level.

Comment: “after wakeup we can attempt to acquire a work item”— that implies that the attempt to acquire a work item is thread safe in any way. And I can’t imagine any reason to make that acquisition use a different lock than the condition check for the availability of an item. Of course, you could release that lock in between if you re-check afterwards but what would be the advantage of that? That would combine more necessary checks with more lock acquisition operations.

Comment: The point is that acquisition can be a lock-free CAS operation. There are well-known lock-free queue implementations.

Comment: Well, when `Object.wait` and `Object.notify` were implemented, there was no CAS support in Java (there wasn’t until Java 5). Combining CAS with an optional wait operation is exactly what [`AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.html) offers now. And it’s basically what a lock does internally, CAS to owned mode and wait if that failed. So in some way we can still say there is no wait without lock, even if we build a data structure which does not wait in the uncontended mode. lock-free normally implies wait-free

Comment: I tihnk the semantics of what I'm aiming for are those of a Semaphore, but with a saturating counter (just like the permit in `park`/`unpark`). So a custom implementation powered by `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` could be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, Java's built-in monitors (`synchronized` and `wait`) are more efficient than many may think. See [biased locking](https://blogs.oracle.com/dave/entry/biased_locking_in_hotspot), and there are further improvements planned that make use of hardware transactional memory.

Second, the mechanism you're looking for and the one provided by `synchronized`/`wait` serve difference purposes. The latter protects some guarded resource, and must contain a lock because it assumes that following `wait` you want to be inside the critical section. What you're looking for is provided by other Java concurrency primitives like [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), [`Phaser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) or [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Comment: Biased locking only applies to uncontended locks only so it isn't relevant here. And I'm not counting on any overheads of a specific implementation, but just the base price of mutual exclusion.

Comment: But on the second point I agree. I think `Semaphore` is the best match.

Comment: The biased "lock" is just part of the entire locking inflation mechanism in HotSpot and similar JVMs. See more [here](http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff/2010-01-09-biased-locking).

Comment: Thanks, but you seem to assume more ignorance on my part than actually exists.